# Supabase SQL Editor upstream request timeout

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I am trying to create a column of ts vecotrs for almost 150 000 rows and add index.

```sql
alter table notices add column fts_en tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
   to_tsvector(
        'simple', 
        id || ' ' ||  
        coalesce(title->>'en', '') || ' ' ||  
        array_to_string_immutable( title_short,' '::text) 
     )  
    ) STORED;

create index gin_fts_en on notices using gin (fts_en);
```

Running this in Supabase online SQL editor returnes this error:

```
upstream request timeout
```

But in fact all ts vectors rows were created correctly and indexed properly as well.

I sucesfully updated and checked longer timeout using:

```sql
alter role postgres set statement_timeout = '240s';

SELECT *
FROM   pg_settings
WHERE  name = 'statement_timeout';
```

But the error measage in online Supabase SQL edirot is still there.

Answer (score 3):

So after discussion with Supabase supoort it seems at this time there is no way to change timeout of the Supabase online SQL editor which is 15s.

The only workouaround is to run "time consuming" statements using standard API (I set up simple node app for such service queries) and not using Supabase  online editor. The timeouts from API can be changed following [Supabase Documentation - Timeouts](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/timeouts)

Comment: I've found that connecting to the database from a client like postico for example has a longer 2 minute timeout